# Pass touch from UIScrollView to UIButton underneath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Here's my setup:
I have one main view, which has several `UIButtons` inside, as well as a `UIScrollView`. The `UIScrollView` has two `UIImageView`s within it. The `UIScrollView` in the layer order is on top of the `UIButtons`.

What I would like to happen is that the `UIScrollView` would pass touches to the `UIButtons` underneath it if the touches within the `UIScrollView` are not on either `UIImageView`.

Any idea on how to set this up?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the hit testing mechanisms of the scroll view to accomplish exactly what you are asking, but honestly that is more work than you need to do any may well give unexpected results.

A better approach would be to add a tap gesture recognizer to the scroll view and have the handler perform the same action as the corresponding button.

EDIT:

Based on a better understanding of what you are trying to do, you should make your buttons subviews of a custom UIScrollView and override -layoutSubviews to dynamically reposition them so that they stay in a fixed location.  If you can't/don't want to subclass UIScrollView, you can try an alternate approach that I outlined in response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891940/how-to-have-non-scrolling-content-in-a-uiscrollview).

Comment: This makes sense, however I have 3 UIButtons underneath the UIScrollView. How would I know which action to trigger?

Comment: You would need to look at point returned by UIGestureRecognizer's  -locationInView: (in the handler method) and write some (presumably simple) mathematical logic to determine, based on the location, which action to use.